# Trace arguments from Ajax JQuery to [WebMethod]

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

At `Webmethod`

```
[WebMethod]
public static List<UserModel> GetUsers()
```

How to know name and type of arguments if we don't know about client side.
For example: I can get page if I know the name and type then I have method like this:

```
[WebMethod]
public static List<UserModel> GetUsers(int page)
```

I search then found this: [How do I get the parameter values from in a web service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5156708/how-do-i-get-the-parameter-values-from-in-a-web-service?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)
However, PostSharp not such as my expected.

Comment: what do you mean here , you dont know client side at all ?

Comment: you can use `HttpContext.Current` inside web service.